# Identify duplicate lines in a file that have 2 fields using linux command line

Tags: linux, string, for-loop, command-line, counter

i have a file composed of 2 fields  that contains long list of entries  where the first fields is the id.the second field is a counter

what i want is to display the duplicated id

example of the file:

```
tXXXXXXXXXX   12345
tXXXXXXXXXX   53321
tXXXXXXXXXXXX 422642
```

i know the logic of how i solve this  problem  that i need to do an iteration or a loop in the file but i do not know how to write the syntax of the command.

i will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you just want a list of duplicate IDs in the file, then this can be easily achieved with cut, sort and uniq.

`cat <filename> | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq -d`

If you want to print all the lines with duplicate IDs on, the below can be used:

`FILE=/tmp/sdhjkhsfds ; for dupe in $(cat $FILE | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq -d); do cat $FILE | grep $dupe | awk '{print $1, $2}'; done`

Comment: @ Chris Tomlinson if i need to display the line number of the duplicated id ?

Comment: @devleb would that be the line number of every occurrence of a duplicate or the last? What do you want to happen if there are multiple IDs duplicated?

Comment: @ chris tomlinson need to display  the line number of every occurrence of a duplicate

Comment: Can you give example of the output required?

Comment: 38 tXXXXXXXXX   678 tXXXXXXXX  where the "38" & "678" are  the line number of the duplicated ID (these will be the same ID )

Comment: @devleb the below should work given no strange edge cases.

I would potentially change the cut to awk so that it handles variable amounts of whitespace for columns.

`FILE=/path/to/file ; for dupe in $(cat $FILE | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq -d); do cat -n $FILE | grep $dupe | awk '{print $1, $2}'; done`

Comment: i need 2 things first can you explain the statement ?      second this statement display the line number and that is very good what if i want to display the number of the second field . like this **tXXXXXXXXXX   53321**

Comment: Regarding the second question, do you mean to just print the duplicate lines? That looks like what you are asking?

Comment: It works as follows:
- set a variable holding the file name (as we use it in multiple places so we don't want to repeat ourselves)
- then we run a for loop over the return value of a shell subcommand (when you run a command in $() it is executed and the output is used in it's place)
- inside the for loop, we print the file with line numbers (using `cat -n`) and grep for the current ID that was found (in the subcommand) to be duplicated, these lines are piped to awk which prints the columns we want
....continued in next comment as not enough space

Comment: .....
- the subcommand uses cut to print only the IDs, then uses `uniq -d` to select only duplicates. We use sort in the middle because uniq requires a sorted input to work correctly.

Comment: Then you would just stop cat from printing line numbers:

`FILE=/path/to/file ; for dupe in $(cat $FILE | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq -d); do cat $FILE | grep $dupe | awk '{print $1, $2}'; done`

If these answer are useful, I will edit the answer as I didn't realise how bad the formatting is in comments.

Comment: so if i did understand  the statement correctly what i need to display both fields is to ad beside the **-f1**
  an **-f2** ? right ?

Comment: No, as that `cut` is used to find the duplicate IDs. To do what you want, removing the `-n` from the last use of `cat` should work,

Comment: okk thank you for your help now i understand how it works .. the last statement is the answer in case you want to edit your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
perl -ne '++$i;print $i," ",$_ if $line{$_}++'  FILENAME
```